# My Tip Calculator doesn't work if I get these erors?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm new coding with Swift and I'm doing YouTube's beginner projects to learn, and currently I'm building a tip calculator, but I have the next errors:

[image]

- Non-constant range: argument must be an integer literal
- Instance member 'tipPercentages' cannot be used on type 'ContentView'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

And this is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var checkAmount = ""
@State private var numberPeople = ""
@State private var tipPercentage = 2

let tipPercentages = [10, 15, 20, 25, 0]

var totalPerPerson: Double {
    
    
    let peopleCount = Double(numberPeople) ?? 0
    let tipSelection = Double(tipPercentages[tipPercentage])
    let orderAmount = Double(checkAmount) ?? 0
    
    let tipVaule = (orderAmount / 100) * tipSelection
    let grandTotal = orderAmount + tipVaule
    let amountPerPerson = grandTotal / peopleCount
    
    return amountPerPerson
    
}


var totalAmount: Double {
    let tipSelection = Double(tipPercentages[tipPercentage])
    let orderAmount = Double(checkAmount) ?? 0
    
    let tipValue = (orderAmount / 100 ) * tipSelection
    let grandTotal = orderAmount + tipValue
    
    return grandTotal
    
    
}

var body: some View {
    
    
    NavigationView {
        Form{
            Section{
                TextField("Amount", text: $checkAmount)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                
                TextField("Number of people:", text: $numberPeople).keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("How much tip do you want to leave")) {
                
                
                Picker("Tip Percentage", selection: $tipPercentage){
                    
                    ForEach(0..<tipPercentages.count){
                        Text("\(Self.tipPercentages[$0])%")
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle(])
                
            }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Amount per person")){
                    
                    
                    Text("$\(totalPerPerson, specifier: "$.2f")")

                }
                    
                    Section(header: Text ("Total amount of the check")){
                    
                    Text("$\(totalAmount, specifier: "N.2f")")
                        .foregroundColor(tipPercentage == 4 ? .red : .primary)
                    
                }
                    
                        .navigationBarTitle("SplitTip")
            
        }
    }
    
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear to you about the first error message? Did you understand which part of your code it refers to?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I edited the post, you can see the error there

Answer (score 1):

This is what i found at first glance. Your code is full of typos.

First use this constructor to itterate over the array:

```
ForEach(tipPercentages, id: \.self){ percentage in
          Text("\(percentage)%")
}
```

and change this:

```
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

edit:

The reason for the fatal error is because we changed the selection. Until now you saved the index of the array in `tipPercentage`. Now you save the percentage itself. So you do not longer need to refer to the index.

Remove this:

```
let tipSelection = Double(tipPercentages[tipPercentage])
```

Change this:

```
let tipValue = orderAmount * tipPercentage / 100 //No need for brackets here :)
```

Comment: It works, but now I have a "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" in "    let tipSelection = Double(tipPercentages[tipPercentage])
"

Comment: @Oliver edit the answer and added new explanation.

Comment: Nowadays you can write `.pickerStyle(.segmented)`

Comment: @vadian you can use the enum. But I tried to stay as close as possible to the original code to show the user what he did wrong and not to confuse him any more.